# Trigger before insert/update sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger which inserts / updates parent table before child.

For example: tables `products` (`id, name, categoryId`) and `categories` (`categoryId, name`)

There is a foreign key parent child between them.

I want to add a insert/update trigger to the product that adds categories **BEFORE** update or insert.

All I found until now where [Instead of ..] commands

need help

Comment: SQL Server does **not have** `BEFORE INSERT` triggers. So either you need to use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, or you need to change your approach. You need to explain in more detail *why* you think you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, though....

Comment: Not only is this a little off kilter consider what you are really asking here. You are wanting to create a category dynamically when a product is inserted. Where would the category name come from and how would you know what the categoryId would be? This is like a child giving birth to his parents. It is backwards and just isn't going to work well.